# Android Service Gets Killed

Tags: android

I have a service in my application which gets killed automatically. I have tested my application in Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)and it runs fine, but when i run the same application in Android 4.4.2 the service gets killed automatically. Could anyone tell me the scenario where a service gets killed automatically?

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Can you get a logcat output?

Comment: We aren't going to figure this out without code.

Answer (score 0):

Android system kills the process when the RAM is in pressure (on low memory), it needs to recycle RAM resources by killing the lowest priority of the apps currently running in the background. So you might set the `Service`'s priority to foreground though this thread runs in background.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent services from being killed by android's memory management you should start an On Going notification from the particular service and dismiss it when your service ends